# Media Player is not starting on the service

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications, android-mediaplayer, foreground-service

```
binding.btPlay.setOnClickListener {
            Intent(this,MusicService::class.java).also {
                it.action=MusicService.Action.START.toString()
                startService(it)
            }
        }
```

while starting the service on the click of the button using this code . Service is started with the notification but the music is not playing .
here is the service code

```
override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        prepareMediaPlayer()
    }
    private fun prepareMediaPlayer(){
        val folder= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
        val musicName="song.mp3"
        val musicFile=File(folder,musicName)
        Log.d("file exist","file is------${musicFile.exists()}")
        mediaPlayer= MediaPlayer()
        try {
            mediaPlayer?.setDataSource(musicFile.absolutePath)
            mediaPlayer?.prepare()
            mediaPlayer?.isLooping=true
        }
        catch (e:Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }
```

I have prepare the media player on the oncreate of service class

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        when(intent?.action){
            Action.START.toString()-> start()
            Action.PAUSE.toString()-> pause()
            Action.STOP.toString()-> stop()
        }

        return START_NOT_STICKY
    }
    private fun start(){
        startForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID,createNotification())
        playMusic()

    }
    private fun playMusic(){
        if (mediaPlayer?.isPlaying == false){
            mediaPlayer?.start()
        }
    }
```

here I am trying to play the music , but the music is not playing.

Comment: Is your file exists ? Are you allowed permission like Media Audio in android

Comment: Yes the problem was with the read external storage permission

Comment: Can you please help me with my another question regarding exoplayer ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77117800/how-to-play-the-next-and-previous-song-on-the-media3-player-view

This is the link of that question.