# How to Play the next and previous song on the media3 player view

Tags: android, media-player, exoplayer, foregroundnotification, android-media3

I am implementing a audio app, where I have displayed all the songs in the home fragment with recyclerview and on click of that item a details fragment will open and the audio will start. I am using the media3 playerview on the layout to play the audio. In the player view there is default play , pause , seek and previous and next button is present by default . I want to implement that when the play next or play previous icon is clicked on that player view next and previous song should play from that song list . How can I implement that?

Comment: If you use room database , set up room database with logic find next item data or previous data base on specific id. Like 1,2,3,4,5, you play 3 then use logic find previous item of 3 is 2 and next item of 3 is 4, is that what you want ?

Comment: Actually I am using Firebase firestore database to get the songs

Comment: So just base on your list access data by index

Comment: Actually I don't wanted to make it very complex . on the playerview there idefault ui is present for play next and previous , which can be added by addMediaItem()  but I don't wanted to add every song manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get the list of songs, First create a `MediaItem`:

```
val mediaItems = list.map { 
    MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.parse(it))
}
```

Then, Add `mediaItems` to the player:

```
player.addMediaItems(mediaItems)
```

Now, Define a `ClickListener` on `RecyclerView` item and pass the index of the clicked item to the player to play.

```
player.seekToDefaultPosition(index)
```

Finally, when the user clicks on the next/previous buttons, The player will play the next/previous item from the media items we added.

Additionally, You can use a custom `Controller Layout` for customization and place everything wherever you want. But you need to use Media3 defaults id's to make ExoPlayer set the needed values to them:

```
<androidx.media3.ui.PlayerView
    android:id="@+id/player_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:resize_mode="fixed_width"
    app:surface_type="texture_view"
    app:use_controller="true"
    app:auto_show="true"
    app:hide_on_touch="false"
    app:animation_enabled="false"
    app:controller_layout_id="@layout/music_video_player_controllers"
    app:show_buffering="always"/>
```

You can get the idea with this layout example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/controller_layout"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/charade"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    android:forceDarkAllowed="false"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingVertical="@dimen/_15sdp">

        <androidx.media3.ui.DefaultTimeBar
            android:id="@+id/exo_progress"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_24sdp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:buffered_color="@color/white"
            app:played_color="@color/red"
            app:scrubber_color="@color/red"
            app:unplayed_color="@color/white1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/exo_position"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/_39sdp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/exo_progress"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/exo_progress"
            tool:text="00:00" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/exo_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/_39sdp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/exo_progress"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/exo_progress"
            tool:text="00:00" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/exo_progress"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_28sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_28sdp"
                android:id="@+id/exo_ffwd"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_12sdp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/play_pause_container"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="1dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_seek_forward_24" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textSize="8sp"
                    android:paddingEnd="1dp"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/_6sdp"
                    android:text="15"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:gravity="center"/>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/play_pause_container"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_31sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_31sdp"
                    android:id="@+id/exo_play_pause"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_pause_24"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_28sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_28sdp"
                android:id="@+id/exo_rew"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_12sdp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/play_pause_container"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="1dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_seek_backward_24" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textSize="8sp"
                    android:paddingEnd="1dp"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/_6sdp"
                    android:text="15"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:gravity="center"/>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

PS: Pay attention to the id's like `exo_position`, `exo_duration`.
Press `ctrl` and click on them to see all of the id's you can use.

Comment: On addition to that can you please help me with one more answer , I am initializing  the exoplayer  in the view model and creating and starting the starting the player on the fragment . Now I wanted to use foreground service with that player still using mvvm How can I do that?

Comment: If so please accept the answer as Accepted for question.
For your foreground service, No need to do much. Media3 is helping you with that. You can find an example in this link from media3 session demo:
https://github.com/androidx/media/tree/release/demos/session/src/main/java/androidx/media3/demo/session